# Create Tabs for SharePoint 2010 ListForms - newform and editform

Tags: javascript, jquery, list-form

I have one SP 2010 List having 77 columns and created the `customnewform.aspx` and  `editform.aspx` using SP Designer.But its not user friendly,as user has to scroll down every time for  reaching the 70+ columns and fill the textbox fields,dropdown fields, choice fields with multi selection checkboxes etc.

I would like to be able to break these up into `Tabs` so that the user experience in populating and editing these is not bad.

i checked  [This](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2011/01/18/tabs-for-sharepoint-forms-aspx/)  link for reference, but somehow the code doesn't give me proper tabs and having thrown some errors.
Others pointed me   [This](http://http//sharepointjavascript.wordpress.com/2011/03/12/tabs-for-sharepoint-forms-v2-0/)   link , but the page doesn't exist.

I have tested  [This](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2011/01/18/tabs-for-sharepoint-forms-aspx)  also , but since the  `TabsForSharePointForms.js` file itself is not available for download I am not getting the correct output.

Has anyone did this before / tried with the same? If not can someone point me with other alternatives[except third party tools]. I don't have InfoPath installed in my SP machine.

Answer (score 1):

If the only issue is , you are not able to find TabForSharepointForms JS file? Then you can get it here.

http://spjsfiles.com/index.php?dir=SharePoint+JavaScripts%2FTabsForSharePointForms%2F

https://www.learntogether.org.uk/SiteAssets/TabsForSharePointForms.js

Comment: Rohit, Thanks for the link, let me explore and revert here soon.